# Trouble adding Admob 6.2.1 SDK to my project

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I was developing an application on API 9, 2.3.3 then I changed the build to 4.0.3 because I only had 4.0.3 installed other than 2.3.3 and 2.2 due to admob's policy.

I have tried to embed admob into my Android application but have been failing ever since. I finally did it on my school computer and it works perfectly. However, I imported my project into my own laptop, trying to edit and add on more coding and lots of problems started to arise without even editing any part of the code.

What I know is that my school PCs are using eclipse indigo and I am using juno. 
Is it because I did not import my codes properly or it is my eclipse version or something else?
Here's the dummy code I did.

MainActivity.Java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

XML

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="the right code"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Manifest

```
    <activity 
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

So there is it. I have looked into many sites for help but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move a project in between computers you have to re-import things (because their file path's have changed). Try looking in your imports and seeing if the SDK is still imported.

Whether it is or not, if you are using  ADT tools `r-17` and up then you have to create a `libs/` folder in you main directory, and put a copy of the adMob SDK in there.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: How do i check if the sdk is imported from my project?

Comment: Try importing it again and see what happens you should get an error if it is already imported

Comment: Did it work? If the problem was something other than what I said you should try I would like to know what it was

Comment: Actually I used the wrong option to import my project. I used "Existing android code into workspace" instead of existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Check for updates and installed sdks in your sdk manager in eclipse and check if the admob sdk for your target is installed.

and do not forget to set your application target to google apis x.y

Comment: it is all updated and i do set my application target. It still doesnt help.